# Spark RDD aggregate action behaves strangely

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Here is the code:

```
  val email1 = sc.textFile("/Users/kaiyin/IdeaProjects/learnSpark/src/main/resources/ling-spam/ham/3-378msg3.txt")
  val email2 = sc.textFile("/Users/kaiyin/IdeaProjects/learnSpark/src/main/resources/ling-spam/ham/3-378msg4.txt")
  val email = email1 ++ email2
  println(s"Count check: ${email.count() == email1.count() + email2.count()}")
  val partitionLengths = email.aggregate(Vector.empty[Int])((vec, s) => s.length +: vec, (i1, i2) => i1 ++ i2)
  println(partitionLengths)
  println(partitionLengths.sum == email.map(_.length).sum)
  val partitionLengthsMax = email.aggregate(0)((i: Int, s: String) => {
    println(s"Partition length: ${s.length}")
    i + s.length
  }, (i1, i2) => i1.max(i2))
  println(partitionLengthsMax)
```

Running this in a repl gives this:

```
Count check: true
Vector(244, 0, 31, 96, 0, 23)
true
Partition length: 23
Partition length: 0
Partition length: 96
Partition length: 31
Partition length: 0
Partition length: 244
275
```

First of all, why are there 6 partitions when the setup is `local[4]`? 
And why is the max length not 244? Apparently 275 = 244 + 31.

The complete script can be found here: https://github.com/kindlychung/learnSpark/blob/master/src/main/scala/RDDDemo.scala

Answer (score 0):

> why are there 6 partitions when the setup is local[4]

Note that if `rdd1` has `x` partitions, and `rdd2` has `y` partitions, `rdd1 ++ rdd2` will have `x+y` partitions.

> And why is the max length not 244?

It seems that you're assuming that `aggregate`'s last argument, `combOp: (U, U) ⇒ U`, will only be used to combine results of *separate partitions*. Well, that's not the case: `combOp` is also used to efficiently aggregate results within a partition.

Actually, `RDD.aggregate`'s [implementation](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L1066) is pretty much as follows:

- For each partition, call `iterator.aggregate(zeroValue)(seqOp, compOb)` to aggregate that partition
- Use `compOb` to merge all partitions together

In the first step, the `aggregate` method is `GenTraversableOnce.aggregate`, for which the [ScalaDocs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.0/index.html#scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce) explicitly state:

> The implementation of this operation may operate on an arbitrary number of collection partitions, so `combop` may be invoked an arbitrary number of times

Bottom line - `compOp` is called more than once-per-RDD-partition, hence the results you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

I modify the code piece a bit to see the intermediate result

```
val partitionLengthsMax = email.aggregate(0)(
    (i: Int, s: String) => {
        println(s"$i Partition length: ${s.length} ${s.take(15)}")
        i + s.length
    }, 
    (i1, i2) => {
        println(s"$i1, $i2")
        i1.max(i2)
    })
```

according to Spark doc. The code piece should mean get the max size of sum of sub partition.

```
def aggregate[U](zeroValue: U)(
    seqOp: (U, T) ⇒ U, 
    combOp: (U, U) ⇒ U)(implicit arg0: ClassTag[U]): U
```

> Aggregate the elements of each partition, and then the results for all the partitions, using given combine functions and a neutral "zero value". This function can return a different result type, U, than the type of this RDD, T. Thus, we need one operation for merging a T into an U and one operation for merging two U's, as in scala.TraversableOnce. Both of these functions are allowed to modify and return their first argument instead of creating a new U to avoid memory allocation.